# Confusion regarding sinusoidal synthesis formula,

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier, signal-synthesis

I am reading signal processing first by McClellan

As shown in attached snapshot, we have formula of sinusoidal synthesis

I am confused ,why in expression of x(t), there is a '2' in first line immediately after summation sign but that'2' disappear in 2nd line?[image]

Comment: I also recommend you carefully try to follow the algebra in my answer here:  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/65943/amplitude-reduction-of-simple-moving-average-on-sinusoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second term can be expanded to 
$$\begin{align} 
2|a_k|\left(\frac{ e^{i(2\pi f_k t+\angle a_k)} + e^{-i(2\pi f_k t+\angle a_k)}}{2}\right) 
&= |a_k|e^{i\angle a_k}e^{i(2\pi f_k t)}+|a_k|e^{-i\angle a_k}e^{-i(2\pi f_k t)} \\
&= a_k e^{i(2\pi f_k t)}+a_k^*e^{-i(2\pi f_k t)} \\
\end{align}$$

Since
$a_k=|a_k|e^{i\angle a_k}$ and $a_k^*=|a_k|e^{-i\angle a_k}$ and $\cos\theta=\frac{ e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

Euler's formula:

$$ e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) $$

and

$$ e^{-i\theta} = \cos(\theta) - i \sin(\theta) $$

Add them together:

$$ e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} = 2 \cos(\theta) $$

You should see that in your equation.

From there it is usually stated:

$$ \cos(\theta) = \frac{ e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{ 2 } $$

See my article

- [The Exponential Nature of the Complex Unit Circle](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/754.php)

for a more expansive explanation.