# Coefficient weights of Simple Moving Average (SMA) on SMA

Tags: convolution, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, moving-average, r

A [simple moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average) (SMA: arithmetic mean) is a [low-pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) [FIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response)-filter. When you cascade 2 SMA's with a window of length $n$, so when you apply the second SMA on the output of the first SMA, and you want to know which coefficient weights a filter would have with the same output result, applied to the original signal, the 2 impulse responses (coefficients/weights) need to undergo a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) (non-circular): this should return a vector of $(2*n)-1$ coefficients / weights. I refer to the image below: you have a sinusoidal signal (black), an SMA (blue), and an SMA of this SMA (green), and I compared this to a filter with the "convolution weights":

[image: SMA on SMA vs. convolution weights]

If you do this in R: the command should be `convolve(rep(1/n,n),rep(1/n,n),conj = FALSE,type="open")`, right? Obviously the red curve does not coincide with the green curve. Is there an analytic solution that returns the weight vector for this new moving average? Not just for 1 SMA on 1 SMA, but for $x$ SMA's on $x$ SMA's?

Here's my pretty basic R code (I assume Matlab-users / dsp-engineers understand):

```
n<-10
vperiod<-40
vwave<-sin(2*pi*1/vperiod*(1:(600)))
# 
SMA<-function(x,n)
{
  out<-c()
  for (i in n:length(x))
  {
    out[i]<-(sum((x[(i-(n-1)):i])*rep((1/n),n)))
  }
  out[1:(n-1)]<-out[n]
  return(out)
}
# 
SmaOnSma<-function(x,n)
{
  out<-c()
  cnvweights<-convolve(rep(1/n,n),rep(1/n,n),conj = FALSE,type="open")
  for (i in length(cnvweights):length(x))
  {
    out[i]<-sum(x[(i-(length(cnvweights))+1):i]*cnvweights)
  }
  out[1:(n-1)]<-out[n]
  return(out)
}
# 
plot(vwave[(2*vperiod):(3*vperiod)],type="l",lwd=2,main="SMA on SMA vs. convolution weights");abline(h=0,lty=3,col="gray")
legend("bottomleft",inset=.03,c("signal","SMA of signal","SMA of SMA of signal","Filter with convolution weights"),fill=c("black","blue","green","red"),horiz=FALSE,border="white",box.col="white")
# 
tempwave<-vwave
lines(SMA(tempwave,n)[(2*vperiod):(3*vperiod)],col="blue",lwd=2)
tempwave<-SMA(tempwave,n)
lines(SMA(tempwave,n)[(2*vperiod):(3*vperiod)],col="green",lwd=2)
lines(SmaOnSma(vwave,n)[(2*vperiod):(3*vperiod)],col="red",lwd=2)
```

---

Update:

---

Thanks to the kind answers here is the code in R for a moving average on moving average:

```
smavector<-function(n)
{
  return(rep((1/n),n))
}

SmaOnSma<-function(x,n,nit)
{
  if (nit==1)
  {
    cnvweights<-smavector(n)
  }
  if (nit==2)
  {
    cnvweights<-convolve(smavector(n),smavector(n),conj = TRUE,type="open")
  }
  if (nit>2) 
  {
    cnvweights<-convolve(smavector(n),smavector(n),conj = TRUE,type="open")
    for (j in 1:(nit-2))
    {
      cnvweights<-convolve(smavector(n),cnvweights,conj = TRUE,type="open")
    }
  }
  #
  out<-c()
  for (i in length(cnvweights):length(x))
  {
    out[i]<-sum(x[(i-(length(cnvweights))+1):i]*cnvweights)
  }
  out[1:(n-1)]<-out[n]
  return(out)
}
```

I initially thought this could be a method for estimating the instantaneous frequency of a smooth curve, by correcting for the SMA's frequency response, as per my previous [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/65943/amplitude-reduction-of-simple-moving-average-on-sinusoid) on SE: which was calculated as ($(sin(n*(\pi/p)))/(n*sin(\pi/p))$), (with p = the period of the wave = 1/frequency), but it becomes clear that with every iteration, the length of the weight vector grows by a factor of $(2*n)+1$ the previous weight vector length. Even if you do only half the iterations and multiply with $-1$, the minimum length of required input data (with the same frequency), is still $2$ times the period + $1$.

[image: Frequency-response-corrected SMA on SMA as Ifreq estimate]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The green curve in your plot corresponds to the correct result. The red curve is wrong, because the weights in the vector `cnvweights` are in the wrong order (left and right halves are interchanged). The correct way to compute those weights is

`cnvweights <- convolve(rep(1/n,n), rev(rep(1/n,n)), conj = TRUE, type = "open")`

According to the [R documentation of the function 'convolve'](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/convolve), you need to use `conj = TRUE` for standard convolution.

Comment: yes, of course, thanks; as I wrote below: the Sma on Sma triangular coefficient weights can also be calculated like this: c(1:n*(1/n^2),rev(1:n*(1/n^2))[2:n])

Comment: I see that if you repeat the convolution, it results in multi-pass MA's, where the number of passes is a power of 2. 1 convolution = SMaOfSma, 2 convolutions: SMaOfSmaOfSmaOfSma. 3 convulations= 8 iterations. Would there be a direct way to calculate the weights for a number of iterations that is not a power of 2? e.g. SmaOfSmaOfSma?

Comment: @MisterH: Just repeat convolution with one sequence always being rectangular.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s are pretty good source on the subject:  http://www.dspguide.com/ch15/4.htm

A single moving average is a boxcar. Two is a triangle. Beyond that, it will start to approach a Gaussian.